# Jenkins: email cucumber report as 1 file

Tags: email, jenkins, cucumber

I am using Email-ext Jenkins plugin to send email after build is completed. I need to send cucumber report, which contain index.html file and some .js and .css files. 
I am sending them like:

```
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/index.html"}
<script>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/formatter.js"}
</script>
<script>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"}
</script>
<script>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/report.js"}
</script>
<style>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/style.css"}
</style>
```

The result file can be processed by browser, but the outlook is not able to run it.

Can cucumber generate reports in ready .html file, or how can I fix it?

Comment: I cant answer your specific question, but what about storing those html files on jenkins and have jenkins email a to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Selenium to build target/cucumber/index.html file, all my styles are stored in .css in Jenkins workspace, I provided links to them and everything worked.

Comment: How are you sending the mail from jenkins and where are you giving the script you mentioned above `${FILE,path="target/cucumber/index.html"}
<script>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/formatter.js"}
</script>
<script>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"}
</script>
<script>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/report.js"}
</script>
<style>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/style.css"}
</style>`

Comment: How are you sending the mail from jenkins and where are you giving the script you mentioned above `${FILE,path="target/cucumber/index.html"}
<script>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/formatter.js"}
</script>
<script>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"}
</script>
<script>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/report.js"}
</script>
<style>
${FILE,path="target/cucumber/style.css"}
</style>`